# Change the icon name in the notification area in windows in Java

Tags: java, swing, system-tray, trayicon

I created a program that supports system tray notifications. I set an icon with a tooltip and balloon message for my system tray. When i start the program the icon appears in the Notification Area Icons in Windows and the Default Name next to it is Java(TM) Platform SE Binary. Can I change this default name to a custom name like my program name?

Comment: That's the description from the .exe that is used to run the app. The simplest way to get a custom icon is to have a custom exe launcher with the appropriate description, rather than just invoking `java(w).exe` from a script

Answer (score 5):

please caused with this code too

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MenuItem;
import java.awt.PopupMenu;
import java.awt.SystemTray;
import java.awt.TrayIcon;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class ActiveTray {

    private SystemTray tray;
    private TrayIcon trayIcon;
    private Icon icon, icon1;
    private Image image, image1;
    private Timer timer;

    public ActiveTray() {
        if (SystemTray.isSupported() == false) {
            System.err.println("No system tray available");
            return;
        }
        tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
        PropertyChangeListener propListener = new PropertyChangeListener() {

            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                TrayIcon oldTray[] = (TrayIcon[]) evt.getOldValue();
                TrayIcon newTray[] = (TrayIcon[]) evt.getNewValue();
                System.out.println(oldTray.length + " / " + newTray.length);
            }
        };
        tray.addPropertyChangeListener("trayIcons", propListener);
        icon = new BevelArrowIcon(BevelArrowIcon.UP, false, false);
        image = iconToImage(icon);
        icon1 = new BevelArrowIcon(BevelArrowIcon.DOWN, false, false);
        image1 = iconToImage(icon1);
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
        MenuItem item = new MenuItem("Hello, World");
        trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Tip Text", popup);
        ActionListener menuActionListener = new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                trayIcon.displayMessage("Good-bye", "Cruel World",
                        TrayIcon.MessageType.WARNING);
            }
        };
        item.addActionListener(menuActionListener);
        popup.add(item);
        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tray.remove(trayIcon);
            }
        };
        trayIcon.addActionListener(actionListener);
        try {
            tray.add(trayIcon);
            start();
        } catch (AWTException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ActiveTray.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    private void start() {
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(125, updateCol());
        timer.start();
        trayIcon.displayMessage(null, "  Aplication Loaded  ", TrayIcon.MessageType.NONE);
    }

    private Action updateCol() {
        return new AbstractAction("Icon load action") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Image img = trayIcon.getImage();
                        if (img == image) {
                            trayIcon.setImage(image1);
                        } else {
                            trayIcon.setImage(image);
                        }
                    }
                };
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ActiveTray activeTray = new ActiveTray();
    }

    static Image iconToImage(Icon icon) {
        if (icon instanceof ImageIcon) {
            return ((ImageIcon) icon).getImage();
        } else {
            int w = icon.getIconWidth();
            int h = icon.getIconHeight();
            GraphicsEnvironment ge =
                    GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
            GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
            BufferedImage image = gc.createCompatibleImage(w, h);
            Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
            icon.paintIcon(null, g, 0, 0);
            g.dispose();
            return image;
        }
    }

    static class BevelArrowIcon implements Icon {

        public static final int UP = 0;         // direction
        public static final int DOWN = 1;
        private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 16;
        private Color edge1;
        private Color edge2;
        private Color fill;
        private int size;
        private int direction;

        public BevelArrowIcon(int direction, boolean isRaisedView,
                boolean isPressedView) {
            if (isRaisedView) {
                if (isPressedView) {
                    init(UIManager.getColor("controlLtHighlight"),
                            UIManager.getColor("controlDkShadow"),
                            UIManager.getColor("controlShadow"),
                            DEFAULT_SIZE, direction);
                } else {
                    init(UIManager.getColor("controlHighlight"),
                            UIManager.getColor("controlShadow"),
                            UIManager.getColor("control"),
                            DEFAULT_SIZE, direction);
                }
            } else {
                if (isPressedView) {
                    init(UIManager.getColor("controlDkShadow"),
                            UIManager.getColor("controlLtHighlight"),
                            UIManager.getColor("controlShadow"),
                            DEFAULT_SIZE, direction);
                } else {
                    init(UIManager.getColor("controlShadow"),
                            UIManager.getColor("controlHighlight"),
                            UIManager.getColor("control"),
                            DEFAULT_SIZE, direction);
                }
            }
        }

        public BevelArrowIcon(Color edge1, Color edge2, Color fill,
                int size, int direction) {
            init(edge1, edge2, fill, size, direction);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
            switch (direction) {
                case DOWN:
                    drawDownArrow(g, x, y);
                    break;
                case UP:
                    drawUpArrow(g, x, y);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconWidth() {
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconHeight() {
            return size;
        }

        private void init(Color edge1, Color edge2, Color fill,
                int size, int direction) {
            edge1 = Color.red;
            edge2 = Color.blue;
            this.edge1 = edge1;
            this.edge2 = edge2;
            this.fill = fill;
            this.size = size;
            this.direction = direction;
        }

        private void drawDownArrow(Graphics g, int xo, int yo) {
            g.setColor(edge1);
            g.drawLine(xo, yo, xo + size - 1, yo);
            g.drawLine(xo, yo + 1, xo + size - 3, yo + 1);
            g.setColor(edge2);
            g.drawLine(xo + size - 2, yo + 1, xo + size - 1, yo + 1);
            int x = xo + 1;
            int y = yo + 2;
            int dx = size - 6;
            while (y + 1 < yo + size) {
                g.setColor(edge1);
                g.drawLine(x, y, x + 1, y);
                g.drawLine(x, y + 1, x + 1, y + 1);
                if (0 < dx) {
                    g.setColor(fill);
                    g.drawLine(x + 2, y, x + 1 + dx, y);
                    g.drawLine(x + 2, y + 1, x + 1 + dx, y + 1);
                }
                g.setColor(edge2);
                g.drawLine(x + dx + 2, y, x + dx + 3, y);
                g.drawLine(x + dx + 2, y + 1, x + dx + 3, y + 1);
                x += 1;
                y += 2;
                dx -= 2;
            }
            g.setColor(edge1);
            g.drawLine(xo + (size / 2), yo + size - 1, xo
                    + (size / 2), yo + size - 1);
        }

        private void drawUpArrow(Graphics g, int xo, int yo) {
            g.setColor(edge1);
            int x = xo + (size / 2);
            g.drawLine(x, yo, x, yo);
            x--;
            int y = yo + 1;
            int dx = 0;
            while (y + 3 < yo + size) {
                g.setColor(edge1);
                g.drawLine(x, y, x + 1, y);
                g.drawLine(x, y + 1, x + 1, y + 1);
                if (0 < dx) {
                    g.setColor(fill);
                    g.drawLine(x + 2, y, x + 1 + dx, y);
                    g.drawLine(x + 2, y + 1, x + 1 + dx, y + 1);
                }
                g.setColor(edge2);
                g.drawLine(x + dx + 2, y, x + dx + 3, y);
                g.drawLine(x + dx + 2, y + 1, x + dx + 3, y + 1);
                x -= 1;
                y += 2;
                dx += 2;
            }
            g.setColor(edge1);
            g.drawLine(xo, yo + size - 3, xo + 1, yo + size - 3);
            g.setColor(edge2);
            g.drawLine(xo + 2, yo + size - 2, xo + size - 1, yo + size - 2);
            g.drawLine(xo, yo + size - 1, xo + size, yo + size - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue today. As Petesh mentioned in the comment, I used a custom launcher to solve this.

### [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/index.html)

> Launch4j is a cross-platform tool for wrapping Java applications distributed as jars in lightweight Windows native executables.

Here are the steps I took to create it:

1. Basic

   1. Set an output file name
   2. Select "Don't wrap the jar, launch only"
   3. Enter the relative path of the .jar file
      (I recommend using the same folder and for .exe and .jar file)
2. Classpath
   this is necessary since we won't launch through javaw.exe or java.exe
   simply navigating to the .jar file under "Main class" should be enough
   you should see your main class appear and the list should be empty
3. Header
   Header Type: ***JNI GUI (beta)***, from the documentation:

   > When JNI headers are used the JVM is created directly by the launch4j wrapper executable instead of running java/javaw launchers. The process name will be the same as the wrapper.
4. JRE

   1. Enter an appropriate minimum JRE version
   2. ***Select 32-bit only***, JNI headers are currently incompatible with 64-Bit JRE
5. Version Info

   1. Check add version info
   2. Fill out all required fields
      The ***File description*** entry is shown in the windows notification

Now all that's left to do is save the configuration and build.
You will see a warning like this:

> WARNING: Some features are not implemented in JNI headers, see documentation.

These limitations can be found [here](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Configuration_file) under <headerType>.

You could of course use entirely different options like bundled JRE or bundling the .jar inside of the .exe file.